# recursive factorial function

Tags: python, recursion, factorial

How can I combine these two functions into one recursive function to have this result:

```
factorial(6)

1! = 1
2! = 2
3! = 6
4! = 24
5! = 120
6! = 720
```

**This is the current code for my factorial function:**

```
def factorial(n):
   if n < 1:   # base case
       return 1
   else:
       return n * factorial(n - 1)  # recursive call


def fact(n):
   for i in range(1, n+1 ):
       print "%2d! = %d" % (i, factorial(i))
```

and the output that this code produces is the following:

```
fact(6)

1! = 1
2! = 2
3! = 6
4! = 24
5! = 120
6! = 720
```

As you see, the execution of these two functions gives me correct answers, but I just wanted to simplify the two functions to a single recursive function.

Comment: I don't get any reason to combine both into one function.

Comment: Hmm. Is this homework? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Don't. It looks fine the way it is. Combining them will just make things more difficult.

Comment: @ FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: last year exam ...  hahah .... I wish I could take you guys with me to write my exam for me but it's not possible :P

Comment: The asker had possibly graduated since the question was set. Anyway, I hope the teacher who wanted them to implement the *factorial recursively* told them that the efficiency of the recursive solution is so terrible that it should never be allowed. :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

We can combine the two functions to this single recursive function:

```
def factorial(n):
   if n < 1:   # base case
       return 1
   else:
       returnNumber = n * factorial(n - 1)  # recursive call
       print(str(n) + '! = ' + str(returnNumber))
       return returnNumber
```

Answer (score 27):

2 lines of code:

```
def fac(n):
    return 1 if (n < 1) else n * fac(n-1)
```

Test it:

```
print fac(4)
```

Result:

```
24
```

Answer (score 7):

```
def factorial(n):
    result = 1 if n <= 1 else n * factorial(n - 1)
    print '%d! = %d' % (n, result)
    return result
```

Answer (score 5):

a short one:

```
def fac(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * fac(n-1)
print fac(0)
```

Answer (score 4):

I've no experience with Python, but something like this?

```
def factorial( n ):
   if n <1:   # base case
       return 1
   else:
       f = n * factorial( n - 1 )  # recursive call
       print "%2d! = %d" % ( n, f )
       return f
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that this is correct, but since OP said it's for an exam, I won't go into any further details...

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
def factorial( n ):
   if n <1:   # base case
       print "%2d! = %d" % (n, n)
       return 1
   else:
       temp = factorial( n - 1 )
       print "%2d! = %d" % (n, n*temp)
       return n * temp  # recursive call
```

One thing I noticed is that you are returning '1' for n<1, that means your function will return 1 even for negative numbers. You may want to fix that.

Answer (score 3):

Is this homework by any chance?

```
def traced_factorial(n):
  def factorial(n):
    if n <= 1:
      return 1
    return n * factorial(n - 1)
  for i in range(1, n + 1):
    print '%2d! = %d' %(i, factorial(i))
```

Give [PEP227](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0227/) a read for more details.  The short of it is that Python lets you define functions within functions.

Comment: @D.Shawley: This is quite inefficient solution, as you calculate factorial(1) `n` times, factorial(2) `n-1` times, factorial(3) `n-2` times and so on...

Answer (score 2):

```
fac = lambda x: 1 if x == 0 else x * fac(x - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

One more

```
def fact(x):
    if x in {0, 1}:
        return 1
    else:
        return x * fact(x-1)

for x in range(0,10):
    print '%d! = %d' %(x, fact(x))
```

Comment: Mathematically 0! evaluates to 1. So the first part of your conditional should be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know the factorial of negative numbers, but this will work with all n >= 0:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n >= 0:
        if n == 1 or n == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            n = n * factorial(n-1)
            return n

    return 'error'
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use these 4 lines of code...

```
   def factorial(n):
        f = lambda n: n * f(n - 1) if n > 1 else 1

        for x in range(n):
            print('{}! = {}'.format(x + 1, factorial(x + 1)))
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  The second reference to `factorial()` should instead be `f()`

Answer (score 0):

And for the first time calculate the factorial using recursive and the while loop.

```
def factorial(n):
    while  n >= 1:
        return n * factorial(n - 1)
    return 1
```

Although the option that [TrebledJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10239789/trebledj) wrote in the comments about using `if` is better. Because `while` loop performs more operations (`SETUP_LOOP, POP_BLOCK`) than `if`. The function is slower.

```
def factorial(n):
    if  n >= 1:
        return n * factorial(n - 1)
    return 1
```

timeit -n 10000 -r 10

- `while` 836 µs ± 11.8 µs per loop
- `if` 787 µs ± 7.22 µs per loop

Comment: Although correct, the `while` is redundant as `return` will kick in on the first iteration (and no other iterations will be performed). Changing `while` to `if` is much better.

Comment: What I meant by redundant was the communicative aspect... other coders seeing the function will see `while` and think: "Okay, it's factorial by looping"; then one line later they see `return` and realise it's actually factorial by recursion. (Usually, recursion is a substitute for loops.) And... ah, I see a benchmark. A small difference in performance between while and if, but your new content seems well researched. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.8 you can try factorial function itself.

```
import math
n=int(input())
print(math.factorial(n))
```

For example:

```
Input: 5

Output:120
```

Answer (score -1):

There is always some kind of a loop in recursive functions and some stoping codes which stop the loop:

```
public int recursivefactorial(int number)
{
    if(number==1)
        return 1;
    else
        return recursivefactorial(number-1)*number;
}
```

As you can see the fulfilling the `if` condition leads to the code that actually ends the "loop" and this is the most important part of a recursive function. In contrast, the `else` part of the condition leads to calling `recursivefactorial` function once again which is effectively a kind of loop.

Answer (score -2):

One more =)

```
#FAC calculation

def fakulteta(x):
    if x!=1:
         return x*fakulteta(x-1)
    return 1


print (fakulteta(12))
```

Comment: you will have a recursion error as you don't handle 0 and below