# Need help deciphering a factorial code in Java

Tags: java

I've seen answers using a for loop which I understood, however I came across this code recently and I have no idea how it works.

```
public class learn {

    public static int factorial (int N){
        if (N<=1 ) return 1; // won't this mean that "1" is returned at the end all the time?
        else return (N*factorial (N-1)); /* since there's no variable storing the sum
                                            I don't get how this is working out either, 
                                            won't it just be returned and lost?*/
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(factorial(4));
    }
}
```

Coming from a python background, so maybe I am misunderstanding something about returns in java... **[Edit]** seems like `return 1` is also written in Python, so it's probably not a language issue, I just don't get how recursive functions *end* (I get how the process goes - it's a function that calls itself).

Here's an illustration of how I interpret this code (wrongly):

1. `factorial(4)` is called
2. 4 is more than 1, so the `else` statement will run -- `4*factorial(3)`
3. `factorial(3)` is called - `else` statement runs again -- `3*factorial(2)`
4. `factorial(2)` is called -- `2*factorial(1)`. At this point, we have 4*3*2*1 but the fact that the code only stops at the `if (N<=1) return 1` line means that 1 is returned instead of the sum right? (I'm obviously wrong because the console printed the right number - `24`)

Comment: You should read about recursive functions. See this link : http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~calvin/cs110/RECURSION.html this also explains your factorial program.

Comment: Does the same thing [in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23501605/2071828) make things clearer?

Comment: You should also read about the definition of factorial.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I realised I don't get the Python version either, since that has a `return 1` too. Thanks for asking though, it prompted me to try coding it in Python so I figured it was simply my lack of understanding of the function, not the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> won't this mean that "1" is returned at the end all the time?

No, it will only return 1 when `N` is less than 1. (according to your condition `if (N<=1 ) return 1;`)
For all other cases, it continues recursively.

> since there's no variable storing the sum
>                                               I don't get how this is working out either, 
>                                               won't it just be returned and lost?

When a method returns, it exits the current method and **return to the point of invocation** and **continue from there**. For simplicity, take this scenario: methodA calls methodB, and methodB calls methodC:

```
public void methodA(){
    print("entering method A..");   //(1)methodA invoked..
    methodB();                      //(2)call methodB
    print("exiting method A");      //(8)exit from methodB, continue from here
}

public void methodB(){               
    print("entering method B..");   //(3)mthodB invoked..
    methodC();                      //(4)call methodC
    print("exiting method B");      //(7)exit from methodC, continue from here. exit methodB
}

public void methodC(){
    print("entering method C..");   //(5)methodC invoked..
    print("exiting method C");      //(6)exit methodC, continue from whoever called methodC
}
```

You will get the outpus as follows:

```
entering method A..
entering method B..
entering method C..
exiting method C
exiting method B
exiting method A
```

---

If you can understand the program flow of methodA B and C. Now try to understand a method calling "itself".

```
//Let say N is 3.. 
public static void main(String[] args){
    factorial(3);                    //(9)
}

public static int factorial (int N)  //(1)N:3, (3)N:2, (5)N:1
{
    if (N<=1 ) 
        return 1;                    //(6)Ret 1, return and continue from whoever called me
    else 
        return (N*factorial (N-1));  //(2), (4), (7)Ret 2*1, (8)Ret 3*2*1
}
```

- At (6), it exits the method by returning 1 and continue from the place which called this method. The place where it was called is at (7).
- At (7), it exits the method by returning N*1 (which is 2*1 = 2) and continue from the place which called this method. The place where it was called is at (8).
- At (8), it exits the method by returning N*2 (which is 3*2 = 6) and continue from the place which called this method. The place where it was called is at (9) which is the main method.

Comment: "When a method returns, it exits the current method and return to the point of invocation and continues from there" -- this was what answered my question! I've always thought that `return` meant that the code breaks out from the function and returns the value. This clarified things. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

The if statement only returns 1 if the parameter `N` equals or is smaller than 1, otherwise the else clause will be executed. In the else clause, since it returns a product of parameter `N` and the returning value of `factorial(N-1)`, Java needs to wait for `factorial(N-1)` to return a value in order to do the multiplication and return the value. There is no need to store the value of parameter `N` into a field since a parameter is also a variable, just its value is passed from the method's caller.

In your code, the `factorial` is invoked 4 times.