# how to find how many factorial numbers are within a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have a problem when i try to find if a number is factorial
this is what I've done so far:

```
i = 1
count = 0
while n>1:
    if n % i == 0:
        n /= i
    else:
        break
    i+=1
    if n<=1:
        count += 1
return count
```

but it returns 1 and I don't know how to fix

Comment: Do you want to calculate factorial of a number?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [recursive factorial function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502429/recursive-factorial-function)

Comment: If it returns 1, the number you are checking is a result of a factorial. To get the count to be bigger, you need to run the first part of the code in a loop on multiple numbers. Right now you are checking only a single number, returning 0 or 1.

Comment: @shamis can you make an example please?

Answer (score 1):

As written, the value of `count` in your example code indicates whether or not the number `n` is a factorial number, for a single `n`.

If it is, then at some point `n <= 1`, so count will be incremented, and the value of `count` returned by the function will be `1`. If it is not, then at some point before `n <= 1`, `n % i == 0` will be `False`, the loop will `break`, and the returned value of `count` will be 0.

Note, though, that there is an edge case not covered by your example code as is. Namely, `1` is a factorial number (1! = 1). But if `n` is `1`, the condition on the `while` loop is never `True`, so the function immediately returns `0`. So, you need to change the condition in the `while` loop.

E.g.

```
def isfactorialnumber(n):
    i = 1
    count = 0
    while n >= 1:
        if n % i == 0:
            n /= i
        else:
            break
        i += 1
        if n <= 1:
            count += 1
    return count
```

I have 2 further comments about this code.

First, in the context of this new function, the variable name `count` is misleading. What is it counting? Nothing, really. It can only take 2 values, `1` or `0`. It would be better then, to use a boolean variable, and call it `result` or similar. Even better, get rid of the variable and refactor your code as:

```
def isfactorialnumber(n):
    i = 1
    while n >= 1:
        if n % i == 0:
            n /= i
        else:
            break
        i += 1
        if n <= 1:
            return True
    return False
```

Which is equivalent but a little better.

Second, a more readable, natural way to solve the problem would be to work from bottom-up. That is, solve the problem by generating the factorial numbers, `m` that are less than or equal to `n`, then checking if the last `m` is equal to `n`. This leads to more concise and understandable code IMO.

E.g.

```
def isfactorialnumber(n):
    m = 1
    i = 1
    while m < n:
        m *= i
        i += 1

    return m == n
```

Finally, assuming each number in your file, is on its own line:

```
with open('factorials.txt') as infile:
    print(len([1 for line in infile if isfactorialnumber(int(line))]))
```

Will print the number of factorial numbers in the file `factorials.txt`

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 0
for n in listOfNumbers:
    i = 1
    while n>=1:
        if n % i == 0:
            n /= i
        else:
            break
        i+=1
        if n<=1:
            count += 1
return count
```